# Own format in XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, format, gregorian-calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

I'm trying to save a YYYYww format in a XMLGregorianCalendar, but wasn't able to find any way. Is there any way to only store the year and the week into a XMLGregorianCalendar?

I couldn't find any solutions by using different formater.

Comment: Please show your latest attempt, so we have something to work with.

Comment: A thought, maybe you can use [the `YearWeek` class of ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) instead of `XMLGregorianCalendar`? It means an external dependency, though. But no, `XMLGregorianCalendar` doesn’t know the concepts of a week-based year and a week number.

Answer (score 0):

```
String week = data.getWeek();
week = week.substring(4,6);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(week));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
Date date = cal.getTime();

GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(date);
return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

The solution.

Comment: I tried it with `week` equal to `201749` (week 49 of 2017) and expected `2017-12-04` (December 4, 2017). I got `2018-12-03T14:17:38.136+01:00`. It doesn’t pick up the year, and it includes time of day and time zone offset — probably from my computer’s settings.

Answer (score 0):

I’d go like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter yearWeekFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("YYYYww")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
            .toFormatter();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(week, yearWeekFormatter);
    XMLGregorianCalendar newXgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(date.toString());
    System.out.println(newXgc);
```

Using a `week` string of `201749` (week 49 of 2017) the snippet prints:

> 2017-12-04

It’s also possible that you may do without the `XMLGregorianCalendar` since `LocalDate.toString()` produces the exact same format.

XML doesn’t have a representation of a week. We need to pick a date. As in your own answer I am picking the first day of the week, the Monday. `parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)` specifies that since no day of week is in the string parsed, the first day of the week should be used.

A bit aside, the XML date format resembles ISO 8601, the international standard for date and time formats. But it is not the same. In ISO 8601 as (opposed to XML) you may represent a calendar week in the format `2017-W49`. If you wanted to produce that:

```
    DateTimeFormatter isoWeekFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-'W'ww");
    System.out.println(date.format(isoWeekFormatter));
```

Output:

> 2017-W49

### Links

- [Lexical representation of date-time in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation). Please also see section 3.2.9 through 3.2.14 of the same document for date-related options.
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.